# JPA is ignoring orm.xml

Tags: xml, spring, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm new with the JPA. 
Background:

- IDE: Netbeans 8.2 with NB Springboot plugins installed.
- JAVA 8
- Spring boot 1.5.6

What I want to achieve is Mixing JPA annotations and ORM (for those complex native queries). Having the next resources:

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="com.nexti_dragonstone-console_war_0.0.1PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.nexti.dragonstone.entity.DgMobile</class>
        <class>com.nexti.dragonstone.entity.DgMobileControl</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dragonglass?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

META-INF/orm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <description>Extracted queries for DgMobile repository</description>

    <!-- using JPQL query -->
    <named-query name="DgMobile.findWhereVersionLessThan">
        <query><![CDATA[
            SELECT m FROM DgMobile m WHERE m.version < :version
        ]]></query>
    </named-query>

    <!-- using Native SQL query -->
    <named-native-query name="DgMobile.findWhereVersionGreaterThan" 
        result-class="com.nexti.dragonstone.entity.DgMobile">
        <query><![CDATA[
            SELECT * FROM dg_mobile WHERE version > :version
        ]]></query>
    </named-native-query>

</entity-mappings>
```

DgMobile.java (Entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dg_mobile")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "DgMobile.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM DgMobile d")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "DgMobile.findByIdMobile", query = "SELECT d FROM DgMobile d WHERE d.idMobile = :idMobile")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "DgMobile.findByImei", query = "SELECT d FROM DgMobile d WHERE d.imei = :imei")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "DgMobile.findWhereVersionLessThan", query="SELECT m FROM DgMobile m WHERE m.version < :version")
})
@NamedNativeQueries({

})
public class DgMobile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_mobile", nullable = false)
    private Integer idMobile;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String imei;
...
```

DgMobileRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface DgMobileRepository extends JpaRepository<DgMobile, Integer> {

    //single JPA-JPQL query implementation
    DgMobile findByIdMobile(@Param("id") int idMobile);

    //single JPA-JPQL query implementation with custom param names
    DgMobile findByImei(@Param("imei") String imei );

    //JPA-JPQL implementation for complex or native queries (using an XML file)
    @Query(nativeQuery = false, name = "DgMobile.findWhereVersionLessThan")
    List<DgMobile> findWhereVersionLessThan(@Param("version") int version);

    //JPA-SQL implementation for complex or native queries (using an XML file)
    // with custom param and method names
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, name = "DgMobile.findWhereVersionGreaterThan")
    List<DgMobile> findWhereVersionGreaterThan(@Param("version") int version);

}
```

As you can see, in the last method declared into the Repository I'm trying to use a native sql query declared on my orm.xml file.

When the project is built the next error appears:

> Error creating bean with name 'dgMobileRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property findWhereVersion found for type DgMobile!

I have already tried to use a different name for the orm xml and declare it on persistence.xml, also tried to not declare it since Springboot + JPA by default search on META-INF for it.

I know that many people is according with the practice for deprecating the use of XML in favor of using annotations. But one important reason for me, is that when you work with a lot of complex tables and data, your queries some times are really big and when you copy them to an SQL editor you don't want to spend time formatting them. So, in this case explicitly I wan't to use a mix of JPA annotations and ORM (XML declared) for queries.

The full-code is available on [github](https://github.com/poseidon24/dragonstone-console/tree/jpa-orm-try).

As an additional info, I followed this instructions: https://hahamo.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/jpa-queries-in-xml-files/

Lads, What I'm missing?

Comment: The both files Persistence.xml and orm.xml are in the same folder. Why do you use the prefix "META-INF" in the path to the orm.xml?

Comment: Hi @AlexandrLihonosov I tried multiple escenarios and one of those was to use a different folder into the META-INF, something like: META-INF/jpql/MyEntity-orm.xml.  Anyway, I have just removed the prefix "META-INF" but still getting the same error. It looks like the orm.xml file is not been taking in count.

Comment: suppose its best practice to use a `Long` type as a `id` property. Have you referred the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) on JPA Repository.

Comment: The default location for `orm.xml` is under META-INF (as you have) and there is no need to put it in `persistence.xml`. If your provider doesn't find it when there, then raise a bug on them

Comment: Check your logs, as my first guess is a named query conflict - you have DgVersion.findWhereVersionLessThan defined in both orm.xml and annotations